# Jquery Multiple Accordions on page with

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have created my own jquery based accordion. It utilizes the 'data' attribute in order to trigger the correct hide/show div. Everything is working fine, but I want to expand this so that if there are multiple instances of this on a page, each accordion set can have a slide open. As it sits now, only one slide can be open for any/all instances of the accordion.

How would I make the click action specific to the parent element (.container)?

Please refer to my CodePen sample for additional code.

http://codepen.io/rymill2/pen/qtfLE?editors=101

**Markup:**

```
<div class="contain">
  <div class="centered m-accordion">
     <h3 class="a-trigger">Section Title<span class="a-trigger-arrow"></span></h3>
     <div class="a-content">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eu varius eros. Phasellus fringilla porttitor eros eget condimentum. Vivamus ornare ornare arcu, eu commodo mauris vestibulum at. Fusce sed nibh nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam in ante tempus, imperdiet eros nec, viverra turpis. Cras sem turpis, suscipit dignissim mauris id, faucibus dapibus orci. Nam malesuada eros sapien, vitae pretium lorem elementum non. Suspendisse eros risus, faucibus nec est sit amet, dictum ultricies eros. Ut porttitor lacus sit amet mauris dictum accumsan. Aliquam pulvinar dui quam, vitae dapibus dolor interdum ac. Proin eget justo varius, tincidunt elit ac, semper odio.</p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
var contain = $('.contain'),
trigger = $(".a-trigger"),
arrow = $(".a-trigger-arrow"),
content = $(".a-content");

contain.each(function(i){
  i = i+1;
  $(this).addClass('c-' + i);
});
trigger.each(function(i){
  i = i+1;
  $(this).attr('data-target', 'a' + i);
});
content.each(function(i){
  i = i+1;
  $(this).addClass('a' + i);
});


$(trigger).click(function () {
  //e.stopPropagation();
  var $target = $('.' + $(this).data('target'));

  $(this).addClass('active').find(arrow).addClass('open');
  trigger.not($(this)).removeClass('active').find(arrow).removeClass('open');
  $target.stop().delay(300).slideDown();

  if ($target.is(':visible')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active').find(arrow).removeClass('open');
    $target.stop().slideUp();
  } else {
    $('.a-content:visible').not($(this)).stop().slideUp();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly, you need to be more specific when you initialize your variables:

```
$('.contain').each(function() {
    var contain = $(this),
        trigger = $(this).find(".a-trigger"),
        arrow   = $(this).find(".a-trigger-arrow"),
        content = $(this).find(".a-content");
    ...

    $(trigger).click(function () { ... }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to use this as a basis to fix my issue. I realized I had to be more specific in my if/else statement as well. Thanks again!